# SSL data read and write transfer rate managing efficiently in Server

Tags: c#, ssl, encryption, server, client

How to control data write and read efficiently?
OR 
What are the possible reason for decreasing read/write speed?
Is there any mistake in my code?
Currently it is very slow.

I am using below code:

```
listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
 .....
// Inside AcceptCallback()
dataStream = client.GetStream();
sslStream = new SslStream(dataStream, true, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCert));

sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate);
....
sslState.sslStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, Length, StartSSLSession, sslState);


// Inside StartSSLSession(IAsyncResult ar)
sslStream.Write(responseBuffer);
sslStream.Flush();
```

Please give suggestions or solutions..

Here I attached the image of current length of the data transferring from client to server. Is this possible to increase the length of the client data..?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a buffer between dataStream and sslStream

```
dataStream = client.GetStream();
bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(dataStream);
sslStream = new SslStream(bufferedStream, true, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCert));
```

This will cause output of SslStream to buffer (default buffer size is 4096 bytes) output to the socket's data stream, and therefore send bigger chunks of data much more efficiently.